# What shape should I use in Keras Input class?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run a simple neural network and I've gotten to the point where my features are flat using the following code:

```
training_dataset = (
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        tf.cast(ballast_train[features].values, tf.float64),
        tf.cast(ballast_train[target].values, tf.int32)
    )
)
```

)

```
for features_tensor, target_tensor in training_dataset:
    print(f'features:{features_tensor} target:{target_tensor}')

features:[0.46029711 0.33290338 0.78302964 0.10295655 0.5890411 ] target:5
features:[0.63530873 0.90712946 0.27781778 0.10295655 0.45988258] target:5
features:[0.68413444 0.81390713 0.8448272  0.65073914 0.46771037] target:2
```

Now, I'm trying to run the following code but I'm not able to get the tf.keras.Input() part of the code right.

```
`inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_dataset, epochs=5)`
```

When trying to fit the model, this error occurs:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_10 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

What should go in the "shape" parameter? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62877768/input-shape-of-tf-data-dataset-not-accepted-by-model-fit) has a similar issue, and it may work in your case too.  Try the following to see if it works:

```
model.fit(training_dataset.batch(batch_size), epoch=5)
```

where you will need to provide a value for `batch_size`

If that doesn't work, I always tend to provide my features and samples to the separate arguments `x` and `y` in [tf.keras.Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).  You could try modifying your code to do that instead of combining them in the dataset.